# Python opencv mp4 processing on gpu

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing

I am trying a to make a script that detects specific color in the frame using cv2. CPU version of the code runs same-ish time as the GPU version. Here is GPU snip:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

lower_yellow = np.array([20, 100, 100], dtype=np.uint8)
upper_yellow = np.array([30, 255, 255], dtype=np.uint8)
gpu_lower_yellow = cv2.cuda_GpuMat().upload(lower_yellow)
gpu_upper_yellow = cv2.cuda_GpuMat().upload(upper_yellow)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("path/to/any/video/file.mp4")

start_time = time.time()
frame_number = 1
resolution = 3
while cap.isOpened():
    if frame_number % resolution == 0:
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        if not ret:
            break

        # hsv_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        # masked_frame = get_masked_frame(hsv_frame, "skin")


        gpu_frame = cv2.cuda_GpuMat()
        gpu_frame.upload(frame)
        hsv_frame = cv2.cuda.cvtColor(gpu_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        masked_frame = cv2.cuda.inRange(hsv_frame, gpu_lower_yellow, gpu_upper_yellow )

        total_target_pixel = cv2.cuda.countNonZero(masked_frame)
        # if total_target_pixel > threshold -> do something
        frame_number += 1

end_time = time.time()
elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
print(f"Elapsed time: {elapsed_time} seconds")
```

I do not see any improvements over CPU version of the code and checking the performance panel I can see that GPU is idle. Am I doing it wrong, or is such processing not possible on GPU?

I have correctly installed cudnn and cuda tool kits.

[image]

Comment: that's because time taken for the transfer probably dominates. please take an introductory GPU computing course. they will explain everything you need. do not just wing this. -- [mre] required. `cap` is undefined.

Comment: I agree with Christoph about CPU-GPU-CPU bottleneck, but you can check it by yourself: you can make a dummy frames of specific sizes (e.g. 100x100, 500x500, 1000x1000, 4000x4000, ...), and process them on both CPU and GPU (~100 times for stats like mean and std). If your code snippet is working properly, then at some point you will notice the speed improvement in the GPU setup

Comment: I have updated snip to make it reproducible. I have properly tested the speeds with GPU and it seems like there is ~15% percent speed increase, which is far away from expected. I was looking to see if there is a way to upload full video into GPU(so I skip the CPU step) before the start of the processing and I do not seem able to find a way to do it. Is it even possible with CV2?

Comment: you would need one fat GPU

Comment: @TinoD how is a "fat GPU" gonna help?